# Need fixed height for mutilple tables with one row

Tags: css

Sorry for poor title, but I couldn't think anything better.  I have multiple tables with only one row embedded within another table's `<tr>` tag as follows.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ABCD</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
  <!-- Same code as above but with different content -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want the height of both `<tr>` tags to be same.  I don't want to use `<tr style="height: 20px;">` as it will insert fixed height irrespective of context and it adds extra spaces in many cases.  Outer table has multiple `<td>` tags within `<tr>` tag as opposed to 2 `<td>` tags shown in above example.

The problem I have is as the second table has more content, its height is more.  This content is random and I want all the rows to have same height.  Is this possible?

```
     ___________
_____|ABCDEFCH |
|ABCD| ADASDF  |
-----|_________|
```

**EDIT**

---

In the picture, as 5th row 2nd column has more text, it is taking more space.
[image]

Comment: table tr { height: 100px; } // or whatever height you want

Comment: I don't think TABLES were designed to be used in this way. Can you illustrate what you are trying to display??

Comment: to expand on Bryan's idea - please specify the desired layout outcome (or illustrate it by a drawing), i'm sure there is a better markup option to achieve whatever you want

Comment: @Brant I can't use `table tr {height: 100px;}` as it will add end up with same problem.  Consider a text that takes more rows and more than 100px

Comment: @BryanAllo I want to upload a picture to explain it in a better way but I dont see an option

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your table should look like:

```
    <table border="3" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">DD-004174-09</td>
        <td align="center">ASDFDFRT DFG DFSDFG SDFGSDF SDFSDF</td>
        <td align="center">SDFSDFG SDFGDF </td>
        <td align="center">09/02/2009</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">IGRT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">XXEE</td>
        <td align="center">SDFSDG FGDFGH</td>
        <td align="center">YUTRYU</td>
        <td align="center">4568 DFGDGF DFGDFG </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">EEEE</td>
        <td align="center">AASDFASDFD DFGHDFGH</td>
        <td align="center">SDDS</td>
        <td align="center">2344 GFDT GFDGF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">ASDF</td>
        <td align="center">ASDFDFRT DFG DFSDFG <br />SDFGSDF SDFSDF</td>
        <td align="center">-</td>
        <td align="center">-</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Please do some reading and searching on google.com for how to build your pages in basic HTML and post on here when you encounter a more specific problem.

Some helpful links:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/html-tables/

All the best.

Comment: The problem is my table doesnt look like as you described. Instead of content `DD-004174-09`, I have that content in a table with one row as `<table> <tbody> <tr> <td>DD-004174-09</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`

Comment: That is not how tables are meant to be used. Please study HTML table specs, standards and best practices thoroughly. All the best.